# Amazon request signature does not match the signature you provided

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, api, amazon-product-api

I am trying to get Product Reviews from Amazon but getting this error ,

The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check   your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.

Below is my code ,

```
define('AMAZON_URL','http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?');
define('AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY',--access_key--);
define('AMAZON_SECRET_KEY',--secret_key--);
define('AMAZON_ASSOCIATE_TAG',--tag--);

    $dr['model_no'] = --model_no--;
    $dr['manufacturer'] = --manufacturer--;


    //get amazon data
    $timestamp = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z");//rawurlencode(gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z"));

    $url = "AWSAccessKeyId=".AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY;
    $url .= "&AssociateTag=".AMAZON_ASSOCIATE_TAG;
    $url .= "&IncludeReviewsSummary=True";
    $url .= '&Keywords='.$dr['model_no'];
    $url .= "&Manufacturer=".$dr['manufacturer'];
    $url .= "&Operation=ItemSearch";
    $url .= "&ResponseGroup=Reviews";
    $url .= "&ReviewSort=HelpfulVotes";
    $url .= "&SearchIndex=Electronics";
    $url .= "&Service=AWSECommerceService";
    $url .= "&Timestamp=".$timestamp;
    $url .= "&Version=2013-05-31";

    $prepend = "GET\nwebservices.amazon.com\n/onca/xml\n";
    $prepend_string = $prepend . $url;

    $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", $prepend_string, AMAZON_SECRET_KEY, True));  
    $signature = str_replace("+", "%2B", $signature);
    $signature = str_replace("=", "%3D", $signature);

    // $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", $prepend_string, AMAZON_SECRET_KEY, True));  
    $url = $url.'&Signature=' .$signature;
    // $url = $url.'&Signature=' .rawurlencode($signature);

    echo "$url\n";
    $result = $this->data_api->call_amazon($url);
```

My call_amazon function is

```
public function call_amazon($url)
{
    $url = AMAZON_URL.$url;         
    //initialize curl
            echo "Caalling url: \n" . $url . "\n";
    $ch = curl_init();
    //initilize url to set which servvice to call       
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);        
    //to tell curl that post method is used
    //tell that retrun value as string
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , 1);
    //execute service now
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if(empty($result) || $result===FALSE){
        return '<customError>
                    <status>400</status>
                    <response>false</response>
                </customError>';
    } else {
                    echo "$result \n";
        //return response
        return $result;
    }       
}
```

I had checked the docs and examples and signature looks ok to me. Any suggestions?